# flowtype: inheritance and generic

Tags: reactjs, flowtype

I want to inherit from a `React` component, and define new `Props`. Something like that (got a lot of errors with `Bar`, should completely be wrong):

```
// @flow

class Component<Props> {
    props: Props;

    constructor(props: Props) {
        this.props = props;
    }
}

type FooProps = {
    x: number;
}

class Foo extends Component<FooProps> {
    _render(value: string) {
        return `hello, ${value}`;
    }
    render() {
        return this._render(`${this.props.x}`);
    }
};

type BarProps = {
    x: number;
    y: number;
}

class Bar extends Foo<BarProps> {
    render() {
        return this._render(`${this.props.x} ${this.props.y}`);
    }
}

const foo: Foo = new Foo({x: 1});
const bar: Bar = new Bar({x: 1, y: 2});
```

How should I use flow generics with inheritance? (in the context of React components, if it matters).

Using flow `0.57.2` and react `16.0.0`.

Comment: What do you mean with inheritance? In the case of `React`, inheritance does not play a role when typing components. You just need to type the `props` like you would with `PropType`

Comment: In mean that `Bar` extends `Foo`, and `Bar` changes the type of `props`. I'll think on it again...

Answer (score 0):

the simplest case, creating a new react component and typing the `props` would look like this in ES:

```
// @flow
import React from 'react'

type Props = { books: Array<String>, search: (string) => void }

class SearchList extends React.Component {
  static defaultProps: Props
  props: Props

  render () { /*...*/ }
}

SearchList.defaultProps = { books: [], search: (_) => undefined }
```

EDIT: forgot to mention this is using the [class fields](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields) proposal that is in stage 3. If you are using a bootstrapper like `create-react-app` you can use it. Otherwise you can do:

```
// @flow
import React from 'react'

type Props = { books: Array<String>, search: (string) => void }

class SearchList extends React.Component<Props> {      
  render () { /*...*/ }
}
```

Comment: This give the "errors" (flow 0.57.2 & react 16):  property `Component`. Too few type arguments. Expected at least 1. That's why I'm trying like described here 
 https://flow.org/en/docs/react/components/

Comment: yeah the first example is using the new class fields. You need to use a `babel` plugin to get access to those. The second one should work without that

Comment: do you mean in need to use a `babel` plugin, and give its output to `flow`?

Comment: no, I mean that doing something like `props: Props` inside a `class` definition is actually a class field, which is not supported in ecmascript right now. It is a stage 3 proposal, which means that it will probably get to the language soon, just not yet. In order to get access to features from newer versions of ES that are not available yet, you can use babel plugins. But you don't need to do that. You can also use the current syntax, which is what the second example is doing.

Comment: ok with that, but I was talking about the flow errors, not running the code with nodejs or a brower.

Comment: yeah, my example covers how to type a react component with flow. It's not clear to me which part of flow is not working for you

Comment: oh I see now, you want something like `SubList extends List extends React.Component`? That is considered an [anti-pattern](https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html) in _React_. You can probably use composition or higher order components wherever you might want to build inheritance chains

Comment: you're right. I'm not the author of the code I'm trying to type using flow, so I tried to not change it firstly, but I will git a try to composition.

Comment: They don't say inheritance is an anti-pattern. They just say they never see encountered any cas where they would "recommend" it over composition. I have the same question on types: how would the OP add types to `Bar` in `Bar extends Foo`?